# What does "among whom" refer to?

Tags: grammaticality, pronouns, modifiers

From "Be Nice — You Won’t Finish Last" — By Sarah Maslin Nir

> During the rosy years of elementary school, my inclination to share my
>   dolls and my knack with knock-knock jokes (“Who’s there?” “Tank.”
>   “Tank who?” “You’re welcome!”) were enough to elevate my social
>   status. I was the belle of the playground. Then came my tweens and
>   teens, and mean girls and cool kids. They rose in the ranks not by
>   being amiable but by puffing cigarettes, breaking curfew and pulling
>   pranks on unsuspecting nerds, **among whom** I soon found myself.

1. **among whom** refers to "They"
2. **among whom** refers to "nerds"

The following is a rewrite for the college entrance exam in china. And it retains the **among whom**.

> During the rosy years of elementary school, I enjoyed sharing my dolls
>   and jokes, which allowed me to keep my high social status. I was the
>   queen of the playground. Then came my tweens and teens, and mean girls
>   and cool kids. They rose in the ranks not by being friendly but by
>   smoking cigarettes, breaking rules and playing jokes on others,
>   **among whom** I soon found myself.

1. **among whom** refers to "They"
2. **among whom** refers to "others"

Is there really an ambiguity about the "among whom" here? Or, is it just that I didn't get it?
If there is, how to avoid it?
Would be really grateful for your help.

Comment: Yes, it could be either. You’d need to look at the broader context to disambiguate.

Comment: Actually, it's very clear to me that "among whom" refers to "nerds" in the first case and to "others" in the second. I find this clear grammatically, and I also think the context backs it up. @Lawrence, can you explain why it might refer to "They"? Perhaps there's something I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: It's not "among whom" that is referential but just "whom", whose antecedent is "unsuspecting nerds" in your first example and "others" in your second.

Comment: @IsabelArcher It wasn’t clear whether the author was implying that she had joined the bullies or whether she was a target of the bullying. The text allows either interpretation.

Comment: @Lawrence: The text is unambiguous.

Comment: I don't know if I'd nominate it for a plain english prize though; as presented it feels like it's trying to say too much

Answer (score 10):

No, there is no ambiguity. The author found herself among the people *on whom* pranks/jokes were played. If she had found herself among the 'cool kids', the phrase would immediately follow the mention of them. In fact it follows 'unsuspecting nerds'.

Comment: What about the second example? I would opine that "whom" could refer to "they/them" or "others".

Comment: The Chinese attempt at simplification is poor. Nevertheless, the general guidance is that the relative pronoun refers to the most adjacent noun/substantive.

Comment: I.e. it would have to be "They, among whom I (also) soon found myself, rose in the ranks not by being friendly but by smoking cigarettes, breaking rules and playing jokes on others."